# How to ZIP files without subdirectories inside the ZIP?

Tags: bash, zip

I have CSV files inside `data/processed/`:

```
data
  processed
     file1.CSV
     file2.CSV
     file3.CSV
     file4.CSV
     file5.CSV
```

and I want to create an archive with all these 5 files:

```
data.ZIP
     file1.CSV
     file2.CSV
     file3.CSV
     file4.CSV
     file5.CSV
```

I tried to execute this command:

```
!zip -r data.zip data/processed/
```

However, the ZIP file looks as follows:

```
data.zip
    data
        processed
              file1.CSV
              file2.CSV
              file3.CSV
              file4.CSV
              file5.CSV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-j` to ignore all path information. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

```
   -j
   --junk-paths
          Store  just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not
          store directory names. By default, zip will store the full  path
          (relative to the current directory).
```